# How many ways we can post data from client side to server?

Tags: javascript, php, http

I need to get browser information like User-Agent, Browser Language etc. I am able to get all these information using Java Script but my question is if java script is disabled then how can we get these values? 
Even if we can get these values [like using flash, silverlight, java or other technology] how can we send this info to server?

Comment: Most are included in the server request as HTTP Environment variables: http://www.cgi101.com/class/ch3/text.html

Comment: What back-end are you using?  php?  .net?

Comment: Pretty sure that _“flash, silverlight, java”_ can make HTTP requests … not sure about _“other technology”_ though, so you might have to figure out what that would actually be first of all …

Comment: please read the rules before posting a question. This question is not well formed, does not contain enough information, and is not even about a concrete code problem.

Comment: Basically I am working on device fingerprinting implementation. Here my concern is to get user machine's maximum information. But the problem here is if javascript is turned off on user side then how can we get information[Screen Resolution, Color Depth, Operating System etc] and post to server?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the php function get_browser. It allows you to get information about the users browser.

https://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

The Other option is the global variable $_SERVER.

> $_SERVER is an array containing information such as headers, paths, and script locations. The entries in this array are created by the web server. There is no guarantee that every web server will provide any of these; servers may omit some, or provide others not listed here. That said, a large number of these variables are accounted for in the » CGI/1.1 specification, so you should be able to expect those.

Comment: Basically I am working on device fingerprinting implementation. Here my concern is to get user machine's maximum information. But the problem here is if javascript is turned off on user side then how can we get information[Screen Resolution, Color Depth, Operating System etc] and post to server?